# uninitialized constant Preferences::InstanceMethods::Preference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

trying to use in rails3.2.14 and ruby 1.9.3

added `gem ’preferences’` to `Gemfile` and did `bundle install` 
And as per the gem document I do the following step

```
rails generate migration create_preference
ran rake db:migrate
restarted rails server
```

added some preference to user model

```
 preference :publish_profile, :default => true
```

But when tried to access a preference using

> @user.prefers_publish_profile

I got uninitialized constant **Preferences::InstanceMethods::Preference**
Here is the gem url:-
https://github.com/pluginaweek/preferences

Comment: Please provide the code that produces this error and enough of the stack trace to see what Rails says is wrong with it.

Comment: #my model example
`class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  preference :publish_profile, :default => true
end`
#my view part
`<%= @user.prefers_publish_profile?%>`
got an error **uninitialized constant Preferences::InstanceMethods::Preference**

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant Preferences::InstanceMethods::Preference):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem will besolved by using rails3 branch gem

> gem "preferences", :git
>   =>"git@github.com:skyeagle/preferences.git",:branch =>"rails3"

Thanks